# Automating ssh login: tcl expect interact command behaves weird

Tags: linux, automation, ssh, tcl, expect

I wanted to automate ssh logins. After some research, it seemed like tcl/expect was the route to go.

However, my issue is that when interact takes over my terminal, stuff doesn't work as expected (pun not intended).

For example, if I resize the terminal, it does not "take". Also, sometimes the interact is not responsive, and sometimes it just hangs for no reason. I have included my code below. My question for the code is, am I missing something?

Also, is there a better way to do this (with another scripting language?) I need the terminal to be very responsive, and no different than if I had manually typed ssh on the console.

```
proc Login {username server password} {
    set prompt "(%|>|\#|\\\$) $"

    spawn /usr/bin/ssh $username@$server
    expect { 
        -re "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" {
            exp_send "yes\r"
            exp_continue 
            #continue to match statements within this expect {}
        }

        -nocase "password: " { 
            exp_send "$password\r" 
            interact
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably you can't use `ssh-keygen` to generate RSA/DSA keys for authentication?

Comment: Note that resizing the terminal can happen even when you don't realise it, for example in Gnome Terminal if it is maximised and you go from single-tab to multi-tab, the tab bar appears and reduces the vertical size of all terminals by 1.  This can cause full-screen editors etc to have display problems if they don't get the SIGWINCH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you bring up about 'interact' not noticing that the window has changed size is because, by default, interact only watches the streams of characters.  When you resize the window, a WINCH signal is raised.  By default, Expect has the, uh, default action which is to ignore it. You should use Expect's trap command to catch the SIGWINCH.  Then you can do what you want - for example, propagating the new size to the other side or taking some other local action.

You can find examples in Expect's sample scripts that do this.  And there is an explanation and example in the Expect book of how to handle SIGWINCH.

Comment: The example from the O'Reilly "Exploring Expect" book is [available online if you have a subscription](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/exploring-expect/9781565920903/ch14.html#sigwinchwindow_size_change_signal)

Comment: can the modes for interact and expect be mixed?  So that when expect doesn't pick up anything then interact comes into play?

Comment: Thufir, Not sure what you're asking because interact and expect aren't modes. They're commands. You can intermix them in a script. You can have an interact be the action of an expect match and vice versa - you can have expect be the action of an interact match.

Answer (score 2):

```
spawn ssh my-server.example.net
trap {
    set rows [stty rows]
    set cols [stty columns]
    stty rows $rows columns $cols < $spawn_out(slave,name)
} WINCH
expect {
    "assword: " {send "Let-Me-In-Please\r"}
    "Last login"
}
interact
```

Answer (score 0):

As W. Craig Trader mentions in a comment, the "right" way to do this is to use ssh-keygen to generate a key for authentication.

You can avoid the "continue" prompt by setting `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`.

Comment: Unfortunately `ssh-keygen` is not always an option.  For example, one of the SSH servers at the University of Cambridge serves home directories via CIFS (it's shared with the Windows and Mac user-area clusters) and mounts a user's home directory only after they've logged in.  Therefore, unless you're already logged in, you can't set up a `.ssh/authorized_keys` file, so password authentication is the only option.  But you are right that `ssh-keygen` is the correct way to go in all "normal" circumstances.